# Form with multiple submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, live

I have a form with multiple submit. How can i found which button is submitted ?

```
$("#my_form").live("submit", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form_action = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_data   = $(this).serialize();
    // Bonton ?

    $.post(
        // ...
    );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? The attached code snippet doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.. refer http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: we are using JQuery 1.8.2 =)

Comment: on() doesn't work.$("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

you can verify it using the event parameter

```
$("#my_form").live("submit", function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var form_action = $(this).attr("action");
var form_data   = $(this).serialize();
// Bonton ?

$.post(
    // ...
);
console.log($(event.target)); // this button was clicked


return false;
```

});

Comment: i will try. First time i use javascript.

Comment: i found this ==> var btn = $(this).find(":submit")

Comment: or this : $(document.activeElement)